# How do I control my computer master volume by batch file?

Tags: batch-file, volume, jscript

I have the following batch code. However, this code only turns up my PC volume, but I want to also turn down my volume. How can I achieve this?

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*

:: Batch portion

@echo off

cscript /e:jscript "%~f0"

:: JScript portion */

var shl = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    shl.SendKeys(String.fromCharCode(0xAF));
}
```

Comment: Check out [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html), if you haven't already. It's a simple command-line utility that can give you more control over your volume adjustments, plus provide a number of other useful functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are tested and work here - the keycodes are in the Microsoft link in the comment below.

**Volume control UP.bat**

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*

:: batch portion

@ECHO OFF

cscript /e:jscript "%~f0"


:: JScript portion */

var shl = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    shl.SendKeys(String.fromCharCode(0xAF));
}
```

**Volume control DOWN.bat**

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*

:: batch portion

@ECHO OFF

cscript /e:jscript "%~f0"


:: JScript portion */

var shl = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    shl.SendKeys(String.fromCharCode(0xAE));
}
```

**Original answer follows:**

According to the comment from `Kul-Tigin` below, the correct code should be `AE`

```
shl.SendKeys(String.fromCharCode(0xAF));
```

You can use a utility to show you the keycodes when you press the up and down volume buttons, assuming you find a utility that returns a keycode for them.

The utility will have to show `AF` hex or `175` decimal for your `up` volume key, and then it should show you the correct number for your down volume key.

Comment: +1, and the Virtual-Key Code constants documented (`VK_VOLUME_DOWN`, `VK_VOLUME_UP`) here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Kul-Tigin That's a useful link, thanks. It shows the AF keycode correctly assigned so the keycode for `volume down` should be `AE`